# What are current density in these experiments with neodymium magnet levitation?

Tags: magnetic-fields, induction

Here is the video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=keMpUaoA3Tg

Experimenter throws neodymium magnet into copper tube. Apparently, it induces currents in the copper, which create magnetic fields, resisting magnet movement.

The question is: how large are these currents?

Comment: How strong is the magnet, I guess you can compare it's size with those on sale though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case of a cylinder magnet, 1 cm diameter, 1 cm long, in a 1.2cm copper
pipe seems like a reasonable set of conditions.
The magnet drifts down the pipe (in demos that I've seen); that
means it has reached terminal velocity.  The repulsive force
from induced current ahead of both the N and S poles of the magnet
are retarding the motion, have exactly cancelled gravity in this case, because
acceleration is zero.

So, there's a ring of current below the advancing N pole, 1.2cm diameter,
and a second ring of current (going in the opposite direction) below
the advancing S pole.   Both currents oppose the oncoming B field, each
providing half the retarding force.

force = **B** x **I** * Length_of_wire

m * g = 2 * **B** x **I**_north * pi * (0.012 meters)

so each of the two ring currents is roughly

I  = m * g /(2*pi* 0.012 * B)

For an 0.01 kg magnet, and 0.3 T radial field at the location of the pipe,
that gives us 4.2 amps of current.

Probably that is in a band maybe half a centimeter long, and as thick
as the pipe; the current density can be figured out from that.

To get accurate numbers, you'd need to measure B in the region that
the tube occupies, and put in realistic dimensions for the magnet and the tube, of course.  I've ignored the axial B field entirely, it doesn't 'cut through' the
tube.